# Replace last comma in string with an "and". (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, replace

I'm looking for a good way in Objective-C to replace the last comma in a string with the word "and". Any suggestions?

"Red, Green, Blue, Yellow"

becomes

"Red, Green, Blue and Yellow"

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"....";  
NSRange lastComma = [str rangeOfString:@"," options:NSBackwardsSearch];

if(lastComma.location != NSNotFound) {
    str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:lastComma
                                       withString: @" and"];
}
```

Comment: Wonderful solution! Thanks for a fast answer :)

Comment: What if the last item has a comma? For instance, this 3-item list: `@"Apple, Falls, Far, far away."`

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 13, there is now built-in support for this: [(NS)ListFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslistformatter?language=objc), which, aside from being less code, also handles localization.